# Java: Is there a method to convert ArrayList<Boolean> to boolean[] (primitive array)?

Tags: java

I know it can be done by iterating through the elements, but is there a predefined method or a way to use map?

Comment: Not really (what I know of). I believe you are left to hand-coding it. You may of course try your luck in searching for an external library that can do it.

Comment: What's wrong with https://stackoverflow.com/a/3293970/759042?

Comment: @aha It doesn’t give an array of *primitive* `boolean`.

Comment: Note quite the same (it is about Integer), but maybe this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: And then there is also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5615664/14955

Comment: I’d go for the stream solution given at the bottom of [Alex’ answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24720136/5772882). It should work for `boolean` arrays too.

Answer (score 1):

Apache [ArrayUtils.toPrimitive](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive-java.lang.Boolean:A-boolean-)

> public static boolean[] toPrimitive(Boolean[] array,
>                                       boolean valueForNull) Converts an array of object Booleans to primitives handling null.
>
> This method returns null for a null input array.

However, this method requires a Boolean array, so first you need to convert your list to an array using `toArray`.

```
ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(list.toArray(ArrayUtils.EMPTY_BOOLEAN_OBJECT_ARRAY));
```

You will need to download of of the Apache Commons Lang libraries.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Comment: That cannot be applied to a `List<Boolean>`, only takes `Boolean[]`

Comment: Am total noob, what do I import?

Comment: Ah - yes, but we can probably fix it.

Comment: Can get to Boolean[] by arrlist.toArray(new Boolean[arrlist.size()])

Comment: You want to download the Apache commons lang library. It is full of really useful stuff and worth the download.

Comment: may not work because my code gets run on an autograder and I doubt they have manually downloaded libraries

Comment: Just do it yourself, it is very simple.

Comment: If you can't download a utility library then you may be out of luck, unless there is some trick with streams.